# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:54111/RegisterController' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, cors

I know that there are some other questions on this topic, but no answer could help me.
I am trying to send registration form's data from Angular Cli project to my MVC server side project. What I have done so far:

On Angular, the registration function:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { Route, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { analyzeAndValidateNgModules } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {}
  
 data: any;

   constructor(private snackBar:MatSnackBar, private router: Router, private http:HttpClient){}

   onSubmitRegistration(users: {rEmail: string, rPassword: string, rRepeatPassword: string}){
      console.log(users);

          this.http.post('http://localhost:54111/RegisterController', users, {withCredentials: true}).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
  })
      
   }

   login() {
    //login code
   }
 }
```

On MVC server side, the RegistrationController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using static ServerSide.Controllers.RegisterController;

namespace ServerSide.Controllers
{
    [Route("Register")]
    public class RegisterController : ApiController
    {
        string emailRegister;

        public class Data
        {
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
            public string repeatPass { get; set; }
        }

        [HttpPost, AllowCrossSite]
         [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200/login", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        [Route("api/Register/Posthdf")]
        public IHttpActionResult Posthdf([FromBody] string data)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
                return BadRequest("Date invalide");

            //emailRegister = d.email;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("***EmailRegister " + data + "***");
            return Ok("lalala");
        }
    }
}
```

The WebApiConfig.cs has the following content:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ServerSide.App_Start
{
    public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors();
          //  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Also on server side project, I have a class called AllowCrossSiteAttribute with the following content:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ServerSide.Controllers
{
    public class AllowCrossSiteAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
              filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            //  filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://82.76.132.129:4400");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200/login");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:54111/api/Register");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT");
           // filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:2000");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the registration button, I get this error:
[image]

Could you please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248700/discussion-on-question-by-ionut-access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-http-localhost54).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Controller method should return 200 OK

First, when using ASP.NET Core/Framework, your API controller method should return a `200 OK` success statuscode in order for the CORS header to be sent to the client. To verify this you can intercept the webrequest using DevTools from the webbrowser <kbd>F12</kbd>, and replicate the webrequest in a tool like PostMan or similar. Make sure your API returns a `200 OK` statuscode.

### Check for the presence of an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header

Then you can look if you receive a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header from the API.

### Configure your API

If you don't receive a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from your API, you should configure it to do so.

For .NET Core, you can take a look at [@Albert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73984464/8941307).
For .NET Framework, the documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors).

In the file **WebApiConfig.cs** you need to add the following to `public static void Register` (Thanks to [Ionut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2279454/ionut) for pointing this out!!):

```
config.EnableCors();
```

Since your client (angular app) is atm running at `http://localhost:4200/` and sending AJAX-calls to `https://localhost:54111/....`, you'll need to configure your api by decorating the controller method with the following attribute (.NET Framework)

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

### Additional

Since your post-request to `http://localhost:54111/api/Register` returns `415 (Unsupported Media Type)` it looks like you're POSTing json to your controller method, but didn't specify the `Content-Type: application/json` header in the request (in the client).

Comment: Additionally, in WebApiConfig.cs `config.EnableCors();` should be added in `public static void Register` method.

Comment: I have added another method in the `RegistrationController` class. When I press the Register button I get again the CORS error. I've put the `[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]` right above the newly created method but I still get this CORS error. How could I solve it?

Comment: @Ionut Ah W8... Here again, it can be the same situation as the OP had. Try using an api client application (like Postman) and replicate the webrequest. Check if you actually get a `200 OK` statuscode as response. For .NET, you **MUST** have a 200 statuscode before the CORS response headers are sent to the client! Other than that, I wouldn't actually be able to tell you, I'm affraid

Comment: My bad, I didn't mention what I am trying to do. I am trying to execute a `InsertUser` method on RegistrationController when Register form's button is pressed from Angular Cli project. I have opened a new topic about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74028447/how-to-execute-c-sharp-function-from-angular-cli-button

Answer (score 1):

You need to set cors policy in your applicaton by adding folowing code in program.cs file.

```
string[] origins = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig").GetSection("AllowedOrigins").Value.Split(";");
builder.Services.AddCors(option =>{option.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",builder => 
builder.WithOrigins(origins).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
option.AddPolicy("AllowAll",builder => 
builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());});

put MyConfig section in your appsettings.json with all your allowed origin urls.
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but I'm a little bit confused where this code should be exactly added. I don't have any program.cs file. Should I create it? If yes, where and using what references?

Comment: @lonut you can add the above code where var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); code exist in your application. i hope yours is a dotnet core application

Comment: No, I have a  .NET Framwork application.

Answer (score 1):

You should do 3 things in order to send CORS request to your Dotnet project using Angular

1- Enable CORS on the server side (All of the OPTIONS requests according to your URL should return 200 code with CORS-related headers (Allowed origins, Allowed headers)

See: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

2- Enable allowed origins in your Angular project (You should whitelist the origins you want send request to)

3- Be careful to use headers that are allowed in access-control-allow-headers while you are sending requests.

P.S: Don't use Wildcard for CORS options in your production environment. (It causes critical security problems)