# How to execute C# function from Angular CLI button?

Tags: c#, typescript, angular-cli

I am trying to execute a method on my MVC server side project when Register form's button is pressed from Angular Cli project. What I have done so far:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { Route, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { analyzeAndValidateNgModules } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {}
  
 data: any;

   constructor(private snackBar:MatSnackBar, private router: Router, private http:HttpClient){}

   onSubmitRegistration(users: {rEmail: string, rPassword: string, rRepeatPassword: string}){
      console.log(users);

          this.http.post('http://localhost:54111/RegisterController', users, {withCredentials: true}).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
  })
      
   }

   login() {
    //login code
   }
 }
```

On MVC server side, the RegistrationController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using static ServerSide.Controllers.RegisterController;
using System.Data.SQLite;


namespace ServerSide.Controllers
{
    [Route("Register")]
    public class RegisterController : ApiController
    {
        SQLiteConnection conn;
        public class Data
        {
            public string user { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
            public string repeatPass { get; set; }
        }
        Data d;


        [HttpPost, AllowCrossSite]
        [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        [Route("api/Register/InsertUser")]
        public void InsertUser()
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\ProiectVisualStudio\\Reporting_how-to-use-the-web-report-designer-in-javascript-with-angular-t566422-19.2.3-\\CS\\ServerSide\\App_Data\\RegisterDB.db; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True; "))
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();
                        //  string strSql = "INSERT INTO tbl_Users (User, Password, RepeatPassword) VALUES('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3');";
                        string strSql = "INSERT INTO tbl_Users (User, Password, RepeatPassword) VALUES(" + d.user.ToString() + ", " + d.password.ToString() + ", " + d.repeatPass.ToString() + ");";
                        cmd.CommandText = strSql;

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        // do something…
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("***Eroare conexiune DB: " + ex + "/n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        [HttpPost, AllowCrossSite]
        [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        [Route("api/Register/Posthdf")]
        public IHttpActionResult Posthdf(Data data)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
                return BadRequest("Date invalide");
            
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("***EmailRegister: " + data.user + "***");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("***PasswordRegister: " + data.password + "***");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("***RepeatPasswordRegister: " + data.repeatPass + "***");

            InsertUser(); //I have tried to call the function when the button is pressed
            return Ok(true);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is, when the Register button is clicked, to post data (which is working fine) between client and server and to insert the data (user, password and repeatPassword) to a DB. How could I execute the InsertUser function when the Register button is clicked?

Comment: The route in your `this.http.post` call looks incorrect, it should be something like `'http://localhost:54111/Register/api/Register/InsertUser'` for the code given, though I'd probably change your `[Route("api/Register/InsertUser")]` attribute to simply `[Route("InsertUser")]`. The full route URI would then look like `'http://localhost:54111/Register/InsertUser'`

Comment: @Luke If I change to ` this.http.post('http://localhost:54111/api/Register/InsertUser'...`  I get the error
 `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:54111/api/Register/InsertUser' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
I need both post and insert method to be executed.

Comment: @Luke I have tried to add, using your advice, a new post request along side the post request shown above, but I still cannot execute the InsertUser function. Do you have any other idea?